# How to learn python (effectively)?

Tags: python

Python has modules and import, built-in functions. I am still learning. Python may be easy, but there is something confused for me.
For example,

```
variable = something.function_name()
```

or

```
variable = function_name(something)
```

How are these two different?
Also, there are a lot of functions, modules and I don't remember all. Do I need to know only common used functions?

Comment: this is more of an *object-oriented* rather than python question

Answer (score 1):

I completed some of your code to show the difference. In the first example you have the variable which is the result of function_name() which is a member of the something class.

```
class SomethingClass():
    def function_name(self):
      # do something

# create an instance of this class
something = SomethingClass()

# your code:
variable = something.function_name()
```

In your second example, the function is not a member of any class, but for some reason it is being passed "something", which could be a variable or class instance.

```
# this can be a variable or object
something = "idk"

# your code:
variable = function_name(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

As with any language, you will have to get an understanding of the packaging, modules, syntax, builtins etc.

In your example, the first one is could be used depending on how you import i.e.

```
import something
variable = something.function_name()
```

but you can also do:

```
from something import function_name
variable = function_name()
```

`something` can also be a class/object.

```
class Something:
    def function_name():
        pass

something = Something()
something.function_name()
```

Your second example is completely different and has no relation to the first example because `something` is being used as a variable that you're passing to an already imported or defined `function_name`.

In terms of what you need to remember, standard builtin types like `bool`, `int`, `str`, `dict`, `list`. Refer to this page for [builtin types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). Likewise it is necessary to remember the [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

You will also need to understand the difference between a module, function, class and basic branching/flow control i.e. loops, conditionals etc.

When in doubt always refer to the [python stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html#library-index)

So I recommend you [start at the beginning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and learn from a tutorial provided by Python itself.

I also recommend [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/) to get started as it has exercises etc for you to do. It's a solid resource.

My last piece of advise is that to make readable and maintainable code bases, I strongly advocate using [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) just because it makes you think about what you are inputting and outputting from your functions/methods.